# Call a function via arrow operator

Tags: php, codeception

I have this code and I don't understand very well how $ext->click() works. Should be the same if I use $I->click($ext) and if is not, why?
$ext store the 0 position of $elements array. This is what the $ext have inside http://take.ms/pmoAj

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('get the index');
$I->am('Tester');
$I->wantTo('Add a new contact');
$I->lookForwardTo('Create a new contact in Alegra');

 //Tester

 $I->amGoingTo('Login into my account');
 $I->amOnPage('/user/login');
 $I->see('ingresa');
 $I->fillfield('#email','salva@fake.com');
 $I->fillfield('#password','1464564');
 $I->click('#submit');
 $I->see('Inicio');
 $I->amOnPage('/invoice');
 $I->waitForElement('#gridInvoices .action-icons');
  $index = $I->grabMultiple('#gridInvoices .action-icons img:nth-
  child(6)','class');
 $numero = count($index);
 $buscar = array_search('voidInvoice',$index);

if($buscar == false){
   trigger_error('No hay botones del tipo anular facturas');
 }else{
   $elements = $I->getElements('#gridInvoices #gridview-1047-table tbody tr 
  .action-icons img:nth-child(6)');
   $ext = $elements[$buscar];
   $I->click($ext);
    $I->wait(10);
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: remove credentials from the question or replace it with fake!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Naktibalda I get this if i used $I->click($ext); http://take.ms/4o5qi
If i use $ext->click(); the test pass, what is the difference? how can I call the click function using the $ext variable?

Comment: $ext is an instance of Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement and it has a click method https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/85aa68020ef2cf4fd261b1f1a690052afe67a9e0/lib/Remote/RemoteWebElement.php#L77  WebDriver::click does not expect to get RemoteWebElement as a parameter, it only takes locators: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#click

Comment: so @Naktibalda $ext have inside the "webdriver" class and inside this class is the click function. Is like I'm doing some $ext = new class; and then I use the $ext->click();

Comment: the $ext = new class; is likely i'm instantiating the github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/… WebDriver class inside $ext right?